# how to search a value in a matrix in julia?

Tags: matrix, julia

l have l matrix of m*n (15000* 2300) and l want to extract the values which are  > 3000 or < 700 for the whole matrix then only on columns then only in rows. how can l do that.
we have a function `find( x->(x == 3), m)` which returns the index of a value
but l need that for a matrix and l'm looking for a result like m[1,5], m[2,6] ..... and so on . How can l do that ?

```
m= rand (1:5000,60,40)
```

thank you

Comment: Working from Michael Ohlrogge answer, is `map(x->ind2sub(m,x),find(x-> (x < 700 | x > 3000), m))` what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, a better way might be to use the vector form of `ind2sub` as follows: `collect(zip(ind2sub(m,find(x-> (x < 700 | x > 3000), m))...))`. Without the `collect` this is iterable, which is probably the way the result is used. Same results as previous comment, of course.

Answer (score 7):

**Just extract values satisfying condition**

If you just want to extract the values within your matrix that satisfy your condition, e.g. without needing to know their location, you can just use the `find()` or `filter()` functions directly.  The simplest way is with `filter()`:

```
filter(x-> (x < 700 | x > 3000), m)
```

which will return an array containing just the values that satisfy the conditions.  Similarly, you could use `find()`:

```
idx = find(x-> (x < 700 | x > 3000), m)
m[idx]
```

Note that with multidimensional arrays, you can either access their elements with two indices, e.g. `m[1,2]` or with unidimensional indices, e.g. `m[61]`.  The convention for these unidimensional indices is that they treat, e.g. a matrix as just a unidimensional stack of all of the columns.  Hence, e.g. `m[idx]` in the code above.

**Get Coordinates for matrix entries satisfying the condition**

Above, I mentioned the different coordinate/index options for referring to elements in an Array.  We can go back and forth between them using `ind2sub()` and `sub2ind()`.  Thus, e.g. one way that I could know, in that text above, that `m[1,2]` would be equivalent to `m[61]` would be to use:

```
julia> sub2ind((60,40), 1, 2)
61
```

The first argument of this function specifies the dimensions of your array, and then following that you give the coordinates you are interested in.  It returns the unidimensional index corresponding to them.

This can also easily work in reverse, which is handy if we first use the `find()` function which will give us a unidimensional index:

```
subs = ind2sub((60,40),idx)
```

(we could also use `ind2sub(size(m),idx)` for a bit more convenience)

From the documentation:

> **ind2sub(dims, index) -> subscripts**
>
> Returns a tuple of subscripts into an array with dimensions dims,
>    corresponding to the linear index index.

Thus, the first element of the `subs` object here will be all of the row coordinates of your matrix for locations that satisfy the condition, and the second element of the `subs` object will be all of the column coordinates of the matrix.  Thus, e.g.

```
subs[1][1], subs[2][1]
```

would give you the first full coordinate, for an entry satisfying your condition.

**Extract all rows containing an entry that satisfies the condition**

Thus similarly, if you wanted to find and extract all of the rows that contain an entry satisfying the condition, you could use

```
row_idx = unique(subs[1])
m_rows = m[row_idx,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain indices and values as a tuple with a nice list comprehension:

```
[(i,j,m[i,j]) for i in 1:size(m,1), j in 1:size(m,2) if (m[i,j] > 3000) | (m[i,j] < 700)]
```

or just the m[i,j] values in a list:

```
[m[i,j] for i in 1:size(m,1), j in 1:size(m,2) if (m[i,j] > 3000) | (m[i,j] < 700)]
```

etc. (is that what you're trying to do? sorry, the question is a bit unclear to me).